# Can you make several pages of figures in a row in the middle of a Latex document?

Tags: floats

I have several figures, each of which needs to have its page. I want to put them in consecutive pages of an Overleaf document. The Latex code of these figures are written together, but Overleaf automatically separates them by other text and makes them non-consecutive.

```
\begin{figure*}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.png}
    \caption{caption1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2.png}
    \caption{caption2}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3.png}
    \caption{caption3}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig4.png}
    \caption{caption4}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: The rule for [p] floats is the (combined) height must exceed `\floatpagefraction\textheight` (default 0.5).  It is difficult to imagine a situation where some floats would qualify but not others.  Maybe 3 on the next page and the last at the next \clearpage or figure[t].  Try `\def\floatpagefraction{0.25}`.

Comment: Or use [pt] on the last figure*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the graphs (including captions) possibly taller than `\textheight`, once you've set their widths to `\textheight`? If so, the following approach should still work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{afterpage} % for '\afterpage' macro
\begin{document}

% ... document material
\afterpage{%
\clearpage % flush any queued-up floats
\begin{figure*}[p!]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}
    \caption{caption1}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[p!]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2}
    \caption{caption2}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[p!]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3}
    \caption{caption3}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[p!]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig4}
    \caption{caption4}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage} % end of scope of \afterpage directive
% ... more document material

\end{document}
```

Comment: However, with \afterpage, there'll be one blank page appearing after the text page and the first figure page. Do you know how to eliminate that blank page?

Comment: @consideration - Not sure I understand your comment. For sure, the code I posted above does *not* generate "one blank page appearing after the text page and the first figure page". (If you doubt the veracity of my claim, feel free to compile the test program and see for yourself.) If you're using the `afterpage` machinery in a way that's significantly different from the way I use it above, you need to fill the in the so-far missing details of what it is you're doing.